# Upgrading from Ubuntu 10 to 13.04 while maintaining Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I have installed windows 7 and I have overwritten the GRUB with Ubuntu 10's GRUB.

When I attempt to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04, it presents me with two options:

```
    1. Remove Ubuntu 10
    2. Upgrade from Ubuntu 10.
```

Would upgrading from Ubuntu 10 to Ubuntu 13.04 preserve Windows 7?

Comment: You want to upgrade from Ubuntu 10 so that only the partition that Ubuntu is on gets modified.

Comment: Ya but I'm concerned about Windows 7. I want it to be save and available in New Boot Options by 13.04

Comment: If you are already dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10, then it will still be there after upgrading to 13.04. As *Sparhawk* stated, make a backup of Windows 7 (If you want, clone it by making an image of Windows 7 so that the entire operating system can be restored if something goes wrong) before upgrading.

Comment: well! Thanx! Now I would try it after making backup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows will be preserved. Assuming that you installed each OS on a separate partition, the Ubuntu upgrade will only act on the partition containing Ubuntu. It should not affect the partition containing windows.

(Of course, you should have backups before you upgrade, anyway.)

Comment: Ya I created both OS on different partitions but what I wanna know is whether or not New GRUB would contain the Windows 7 boot option ? Cause Initially Windows 7 boot was replaced by UB 10 boot options !

Comment: When you initially installed Ubuntu 10, it should have replaced the Windows bootloader with GRUB (but still allow you to select and boot into Windows). Was that the case? If so, the upgrade should not change this.

Comment: GRUB will ALWAYS make an entry for any available Windows-partitions when installing. Windows never recognizes Linux, so make shure you install windows first and then Linux with GRUB to have dualboot. Just make shure you take your time and don't destroy anything valuable during partitioning.

Comment: Thanx Zulu34sx that was satisfying!